# Exception in thread : UnexpectedTagNameException

Tags: html, selenium, exception, tagname

I am Trying to Locate Dropdown using Select but its giving me error :

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "input"

Tried with ByIndex,ByValue but its not working

**Code**

```
Select dropdown = new 
Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MainContent_ddlLocale_Input")));
    //dropdown.selectByIndex(2);
     dropdown.selectByValue("Austria: Vienna");
```

**HTML**

```
td class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft" style="width:100%;">
<input id="ctl00_MainContent_ddlLocale_Input" class="rcbInput ui-widget-    content" type="text" value="Austria: Vienna"     name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlLocale" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

As exception clearly saying you are locating the `input` element but trying to work as `select` element.

`new Select()` expect `select` element as input while you are providing `input` element as input.

You need to verify your provided id `ctl00_MainContent_ddlLocale_Input` is the id of `input` element or `select` element.

If in your case the `ctl00_MainContent_ddlLocale_Input` same for both `input` and `select` elements, then you need to try usimg `cssSelector` to specify `select` element as below :-

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select#ctl00_MainContent_ddlLocale_Input"))); 

//dropdown.selectByIndex(2);
dropdown.selectByValue("Austria: Vienna");
```

Hope it helps..:)