# Find an element using selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to use find an element in a list but I'm getting the error:

> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "li"

The element I am looking for is in the list:

```
<span unselectable="on" class="k-input">[SELECT2]</span>
```

And the element is located at:

```
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-index="2">ARKANSAS</li>
```

I am trying to find it using the following java code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.k-input")).click(); Thread.sleep(1000); //it works
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"DriverLicState_listbox\"]/li[3]"))); // error
```

I've tried to select an an element in a list but it seemed to not work either. How can I properly do this?

Comment: That's perfectly reasonable error because `<li>` is not the same tag as `<select>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception in thread : UnexpectedTagNameException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499501/exception-in-thread-unexpectedtagnameexception)

Answer (score 1):

The Select class is designed to work on a "select" element.  The little bit of HTML code you've shown suggests that this is some sort of custom selection control built as a cascading list.  You'll probably have to write your own selenium code to interact with it... a CustomSelect class with appropriate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here there are **two ways** I solved this problem:

I used the Selenium IDE to see more target options.

Option 1: *xpath:idRelative*

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"DriverLicState_listbox\"]/li[3]")).click();
```

Option 2: *xpath:Position*

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[2]/div/ul/li[3]")).click();
```